# C# DateTimePicker stuck in loop

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker in C#.  When I click on it, it expands to show a monthly calendar, when I click the left arrow to go back a month, it changes the value and calls my event.  The event includes too much code to include here but it calls several functions needless to say.
The problem I'm having is that when I click that left arrow it gets stuck in some sort of loop and keeps descending through the months and I can't stop it.  One of the functions that is being called contains a Application.DoEvents() and if I comment that out it doesn't get stuck in the loop, but I need that command to update another section of the interface.  Any idea why this is happening?

I can duplicate it sometimes with this code, sometimes it just does it a couple times, sometimes it gets stuck in the loop.

```
private void DateTimePickerValueChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
afunction(); 
} 

private void afunction() 
{ 
listView1.Clear(); 
panel1.Visible = true; 
Application.DoEvents(); 
}
```

Comment: How about this?  You're doing too much work in the event handler, especially if you need to call DoEvents...

Comment: Why would that cause a problem?

Comment: Does it hang without the DoEvents()?

Comment: @henk he said: One of the functions that is being called contains a Application.DoEvents() and if I comment that out it doesn't get stuck in the loop, but I need that command to update another section of the interface. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It isn't specific to the DoEvents command.  With the DoEvents command commented out, if I move a listView1.Clear() to after my webservice call it causes the same problem, but before it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have the same problem. In my case, instead of calling DoEvents I'm updating a Crystal Report view. The only workaround I found is to update my view upon the CloseUp event instead of ValueChanged or TextChanged.

Scott, how did you finally corrected your problem ?

Comment: I finally decided to just remove the panel I was trying to display, it was more for cosmetic reasons than functionality but I'll give your solution a try. Thanks.

Comment: +1 - The `CloseUp` event solved my problem in something I am working on in a VB.NET project. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

The DateTimePicker ValueChanged event is buggy. Per Microsoft Windows Forms Team on this page https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1290685/debugging-datetimepicker-event-hangs-vs:

"The DateTimePicker control installs a mouse hook as part of its functionality, but when the debugger has the WinForms application stopped on a breakpoint, it allows the possibility of a deadlock if VS happens to get a mouse message. For now, the deadlock is unfortunately a consequence of the DateTimePicker's design. The mouse hook is installed when the drop down is clicked to display the calendar. This means that breakpoints should not be sent in any event handlers which would be called while the calendar is active. We are currently investigating whether it is possible to address this issue and we will update this thread with further information if we are able to make a fix available."

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of the code, try these steps:

1. Comment out the entire event handler
   to see how fast it runs with nothing
   attached to it.
2. Uncomment lines one at a time to see
   which ones are causing the most
   problems.
3. Analyze those method calls.
4. ...
5. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a couple of things.  Get rid of the DoEvents inside of the ChangedEvent.
Call the doevents inside of a seperate function after maybe a period of time (thread.sleep() ?).

I know doevents does cause issues but I rarely use it.

Comment: The problem is that I make a panel visible at the beginning of the event. Do a web service call and then hide the panel.  I have to put the DoEvents after the panel1.visible = true; to actually get it to display while the webservice is called.

Answer (score 0):

event procedure `ValueChanged` :
set parameter in `sender.tag`
enableTimer and execute parameter using sender.tag

**example:**

```
private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTimePicker ThisSender = (DateTimePicker)sender;
        Timer.Tag = ThisSender.Name.ToString() + "=" + ThisSender.Value;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```