# Visual Studio "Not Responding" when I change a datetimepicker value in Winforms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, datetimepicker

I have a WinForms application that has been running great for 10 years. I was running this in Visual Studio 2013 last week and all worked well. NOTHING HAS CHANGED IN MY CODE. Thursday it worked fine. Today it hangs.

Today when I select a date in a DateTimePicker, the ValueChanged is triggered, but Visual Studio instantly goes into "(Not Responding)" mode. I let it run for up to 10 minutes and nothing. Maybe it is stuck in a loop?  It hangs before I even get to the event handler... it shows my breakpoint on the first line of the event handler and the yellow/gold block, but it does not allow me to progress as it is already showing "Not Responding". Also, I just realized, I can manually change the date, but it locks only when I select a date from the calendar.
Per another post, if I set "ShowUpDown" to true, it works. When "ShowUpDown" is set to false, it hangs.
I also tried adding "System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()" to the form load and that didn't help either.

The code could not be simplier:

```
Private Sub dtpStart_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles dtpStart.ValueChanged, dtpEnd.ValueChanged

 ....
 End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you doing inside this event handler? Did you try to put a breakpoint on the first line of your event code and follow what happens?

Comment: @Steve - It hangs before I even get to the event handler... it shows my breakpoint on the first line of the event handler and the yellow/gold block, but it does not allow me to progress as it is already showing "Not Responding". Also, I just realized, I can manually change the date, but it locks only when I hit the dropdown arrow(I will add this to my question)

Comment: Whoever downvoted this. The code has been working correctly for 10 years. Today it is an issue. NOTHING HAS CHANGED IN MY CODE.

Comment: @Steve - (More accurate description)  It hangs before I even get to the event handler... it shows my breakpoint on the first line of the event handler and the yellow/gold block, but it does not allow me to progress as it is already showing "Not Responding". Also, I just realized, I can manually change the date, but it locks only when I hit select a date in the calendar after hitting the dropdown arrow (that causes the calendar to pop up).

Comment: Possibly related: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42179095/2592875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42179095/2592875)

Comment: @TnTinMn - Thank you. This issue disappeared as soon as I installed Microsoft Updates and removed the breakpoint. The breakpoint caused the deadlock. Put this as the solution and I will check the box! Thanks a million!!

Comment: @DanB, if the other answer is the solution, then your question is a duplicate of that and should be closed.  I don't take credit for other's work, but thanks for the thought.

Comment: @TnTinMn - I didn't think of it as a duplicate as the question seemed different (and did not come up in my searches), but you're absolutely correct - I'm all for giving credit where it's due..

Comment: @TnTinMn - After looking at this again, the "dup" question WAS different and while the answer you found applied to me, it did not apply to the question and therefore was not marked as the answer with good reason. I think this is not a dup, but not sure how to change that now that I already marked it as such. Either way, I"m glad to know.

Comment: @DanB,  I don't always take the questions literally as people tend to get myopic when having a problem and don't think to look at more general scenarios.  I found that one by searching "DatetimePicker hangs" and it was the second one that referenced the bug, but the subject answer included text from the now gone MS Connect site, so I picked it as the reference.  Ack, now I just rubbed salt in that wound, darn you MS for deleting a vital information source.